# Iterate over json and concat string to value

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, ansible

I'm trying to create a refind JSON out of a JSON output that I get from AWS
This is the output from AWS (I've reduced line count):

```
{
    "Regions": [
        {
            "Endpoint": "ec2.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com",
            "RegionName": "ap-south-1"
        },
        {
            "Endpoint": "ec2.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com",
            "RegionName": "eu-west-3"
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is my ansible playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: JSON Me
    shell: 'aws --profile="{{ AWS_PROFILE }}" --region="{{ AWS_REGION }}" ec2 describe-regions'
    register: regions_out

  - set_fact:
      regions: "{{ regions_out.stdout | from_json }}"

  - name: print
    shell: echo '"{{ item }}" = abc'
    loop: "{{ regions | json_query('Regions[*].RegionName') }}"
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to pring out `RegionName` and concat text (`= abc`)

However, myoutput looks like this:

```
changed: [localhost] => (item=ap-south-1)
changed: [localhost] => (item=eu-west-3)
```

Trying to filter with `| join(" = abc")` gave an error as the output became one long string instead of a list.

Would appreciate suggestions,
thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: JSON Me
    shell: 'aws --profile="{{ AWS_PROFILE }}" --region="{{ AWS_REGION }}" ec2 describe-regions'
    register: regions_out

  - set_fact:
      regions: "{{ regions_out.stdout | from_json }}"

  - name: print
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item }} = \"ami-...\""
    loop: "{{ regions | json_query('Regions[*].RegionName') }}"
```